# How to load html data once a user authenticates

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Application, lots of html/js => `app.html`

- If a user is authenticated true OAuth/Google-Drive => Have access
- Else its not a logged in user => No access

This could be done server side, but then a OAuth flow would need to be executed on server side and then client side? I could move everything server side but that seems to be a lot of on the app engine resources (eg `getFile()`, `updateFile()`) which could be avoided; only client is taking to his own drive right? cut the middle man out.

I my going the right way about this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, yes, this is correct. You can write Google Drive apps completely in the browser.

Comment: But I have lots of html i dont wan't the no logged in users to see, i could display:none that but that wont help as the user can view source. Just some extra protection i wan't to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you redirect to the actual html page with the GDrive calls after authentication ?

It would go like this : every user lands on the login.html page, which only handles the OAuth part. Once the the OAuth token is retrieved login.html redirects the user to the actual app.html.

More generally though, I cannot see any reason why you would want to hide the code from users who did not authenticate to Drive. Anyway, without an OAuth token this code is useless.

Comment: This is how i'm doing it but the html is sensitive, only logged in users should have access to it, simple as.

Comment: If you want to prevent client access, you'll need some kind of server control.